# Refresh/Update Controls inside usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that has `TabControl` with Dynamic `TabPages` in it. Each pages has usercontrol added using a loop. This is how I add the `usercontrol` in each pages.

```
for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    uctrTab = new XtraTabPagesUserCtrl();
    xtab.TabPages[i].Text = "Table " + (i+1);
    uctrTab.LayoutClicked += new MouseEventHandler(Layout_Click);
    xtab.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(uctrTab);
    xtab.TabPages[i].PageVisible = !xtab.TabPages[i].PageVisible;
}
```

The usercontrol I made has a `DataGridView` in it so i want to refresh the content of it but I dont know how to do that without removing and readding the control back.

right now my solution is

```
 xtab.SelectedTabPage.Controls.Clear();
 uctrTab = new XtraTabPagesUserCtrl();
 uctrTab.LayoutClicked += new MouseEventHandler(Layout_Click);
 xtab.SelectedTabPage.Controls.Add(uctrTab);
```

is there any better way of refreshing the content without having to do that?

Comment: To avoid getting downvoted, first you'll need to show us what you have tried so far..

Comment: @fabricio sorry kind of new to the site... just edited the question... as suggested

Comment: yeah.. now it looks way more better! My suggestion.. first implement a method in your user control like.. public void Refresh(){refresh datagridview data here}. Second, itearate over selected tab page's controls and look for your usercontrol.. something like this.. foreach(Control ctrl in selectedTabPage.Controls){
if(ctrl is XtraTabPagesUserCtrl){
ctrl.Refresh();
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to write my answer here (I did it in the comments section because question was on hold).

My suggestion.. first implement a method in your user control like..

```
public void RefreshGrid()
{
    refresh datagridview data here
}
```

Second, itearate over selected tab page's controls and look for your usercontrol.. something like this..

```
foreach(Control ctrl in selectedTabPage.Controls)
{ 
    if(ctrl is XtraTabPagesUserCtrl)
    { 
        ((XtraTabPagesUserCtrl)ctrl).RefreshGrid(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can shorten the code by doing this: `foreach(var c in selectedTabPage.Controls.OfType<XtraTabPagesUserCtrl>()) { c.Refresh(); }`.

Comment: @Abbas yeah.. you are rigth!

Comment: Thanks @fabricio and Abbas those way if much more faster and right way to do it.